# Images export from excel by PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel, export, изображения

Подскажите, плз, есть ли способ вытянуть из существующего excel файла (Excel2007) вставленные в него картинки. Допустим, я знаю в каком листе и в какой ячейке смотреть надо.

Возможно, есть другой способ, не используя PHPExcel?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.